# Copy files in a directory, to folders with same name as file

Tags: powershell

I have multiple files that I want to copy each file to a folder with same name

For example, the files

```
orange_file100 , orange_file200 , orange_file300 , apple_file120 , apple_file150
```

I want to move each file to a folder that contain part of the filename say orange and apple so the result will be

```
orange\orange_file100
orange\orange_file200
orange\orange_file300

apple\apple_file120
apple\apple_file150
```

How can I do that through powershell, should I use `Get-ChildItem` then `ForEach{Copy-Item)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-Childitem` with a `-File` or `-Directory` to only grab the files or folders in a folder, that way you wont grab a folder and try place it in itself.
For example, the code below will only grab the files in the current directory

```
Get-Childitem -File
```

You can then use some regex to split the names so you can get the fruit name e.g.

```
$String.split('_')[0]
```

You should insert it into a list or array or something to store it, but now you have a list of files and fruit names.

Now you can loop over the list and start to move or copy the files into the right folder structure

```
Foreach($file in $FileList){
    if($file.name -matches $Fruitname){
        if($file.name -notmatch $pwd.path ){
            mkdir $file.name
            cd $file.name
            move-item $file.fullname $pwd
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is just a quick attempt. It probably wont work the first time and you should make adjustments to understand what you are doing.

A few notes

- `$pwd` gets the current directory. I'm assuming `Get-Childitem` returns the list of files in the correct order, so you will get Orange_100, then Orange_200 and so on
- `Get-Childitem` returns a powershell object. The file names can be accessed using `$_.name` or the full path using `$_.fullname`
- If `-matches` doesn't work, you can also try `-like` or `-in`
- I didn't add in the first fruit folder into the code above, but it won't be hard to create

Remember to play around and find whats best for you.